# Is it possible to reopen or edit the content of this question to become less opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based

I'm seeking information about default toString method and hence found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668656), but unfortunately it is closed as opinion based now.

I guess it was closed because some question like "is x useful" may need to include the opinion about x in the answer. But after reading the question, I think it is not totally opinion based because the OP looks like just seeking for examples of using default toString methods, which examples are unlikely opinion based.

I'm not sure if my view is correct, is this question worth to reopen? If not, is it possible to edit the body of question to become less opinion based and then reopen the question?

Comment: Seeking examples would probably make the question Too Broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the question, and I think that the underlying premise could make a good question.

But the question was just terribly executed. It's clear that the author couldn't convey what they were asking. The down votes may have been a result of people's frustration with the repeated editing and stream of clarifications.

The question is really asking if there is any reason to use the default `toString()` method of an object instead of overriding it. This is more of an open ended question that deals more with design, and it seems like it might be a better fit for Programmers.

Personally, I think that the number of down votes makes it hardly worth putting effort into. It's not your question anyway, so you could just ask a new question if you feel that you can make a good question out of it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is right there : [image]

(*Read the last line*)

Of course you may edit & improve the question (and reopen it).

[edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30668656/edit)

Read through : [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

If you intend to re-open the question :

> Reopening a question follows the same process as closing a question.
>
> Users with 3,000 reputation can cast up to 50 reopen votes per day.
>   When a question reaches 5 reopen votes, it is no longer closed, and
>   new answers may be submitted. You may only vote to close or reopen a
>   question once. To cast a reopen vote, click the "reopen" link beneath
>   the question.
>
> Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote.

Refer: [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: It's not his question, so re-writing the whole question to make it ask something completely different wouldn't be appropriate at all.

Comment: @Servy Yes if he intends to ask something different then it wouldn't make sense, but if he wants to improve the same question so as to make it *salvageable* then I think its the right thing to do.

Comment: The entire premise of the question is inherently opinion based.  It's not *possible* to make the question into an appropriate question without *radically* changing what it is inherently asking about.  It's not like the question has formatting problems or bad grammar, it's just inherently asking a kind of question that's not appropriate here.

Comment: @Sery You are probably right. I don't know much about the specific question he is referring to, my answer was to the question above.

Comment: He asked if he can edit that question to make it appropriate.  You've given him actively counter-productive advice, and are encouraging him to make inappropriate edits to a question.

Comment: @Servy That question is **too broad** since it asks about the functionality of method. It could be reopened if the context for it was set right. Its not an off topic question, its just too broad.

Comment: And it's not appropriate to radically change the scope of someone else's question, as I've said several times now.  If he were the question author he could narrow the scope of the question to something more specific, but someone else can't just come along and completely change what the question is asking in order to sufficiently narrow its scope.

Comment: @Servy If it could be narrowed down then if maybe voted to reopen, if not then it would just remain closed. If you feel we should discuss further we shall move to a chat.

Comment: If the *author* wanted to narrow the scope of the question, they could do so.  Someone else cannot just come along and completely change what the question is asking though.  That's not an appropriate edit for someone other than the author to make.  Telling them to make such an edit is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111140/discussion-between-ani-menon-and-servy).